# Variable sc might not have been initialized

Tags: java

I haven't coded in over 2 years and am incredibly rusty, but after going on google for quite a while I can not figure out what I have done wrong. First I will explain this program even if it's very simple. I have a .txt file with 680 numbers, one number per line and am trying to find the frequency of numbers with the range 000-999. I believe I can figure out the frequency part since it seems pretty basic, but I am having trouble figuring out how to import the numbers from the .txt file. This is the error I have:

```
C:\Users\Arthur\Documents\FrequencyStraightPlay\FrequencyStraightPlay.java:17: error: variable sc might not have been initialized
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
               ^
1 error
```

The code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FrequencyStraightPlay {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [] rawNumbers = new int [680];
    int i = 0;

    Scanner sc;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("Numbersnospaces.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not Found!");
    }
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        rawNumbers[i++] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("The Raw Numbers: ");

    for (i = 0; i < 680; i++) {
        System.out.println(rawNumbers[i]);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: The error message tells you **exactly** what the problem is. I suggest your read it closely.

Comment: Did you get "File not found!" in your output?

Comment: just use Scanner sc = null; instead of Scanner sc;

Comment: This is an example of why usually you should initialize a variable along with its declaration. There are reasons to break this rule of thumb, but you must learn the rule first before understanding when to break it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you catch `FileNotFoundException`, then `sc` won't have been initialized.

Place the `while` loop inside the `try` block so you know `sc` has been initialized by the time you get to it.

One might think that the solution is to initialize `sc` to `null` when it's declared, but that's incorrect, because without moving the `while` loop inside the `try` block, you could get a `NullPointerException` if you caught a `FileNotFoundException`; `sc` would still be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the case when file not found. Consider throwing an exception (or return) instead of continuing the code.

Answer (score 0):

if the code in the try catch block throws an exception, value of sc is null. you should not proceed to sc.hasNextInt() once you've caught the exception.

```
try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("Numbersnospaces.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not Found!");
        return; // this will remove that error/warning
    }
```